# Force application to use a specific IP address from running computer

Tags: c#, vb.net, httpwebrequest, ip

I have a server (server A) that has several public IP addresses. I am building a desktop application that will run on server A to fetch data from another server (server B) using the `httpwebrequest` class.

What I would like to do is be able to programatically direct the application to use a specific IP address from the one the server (A) has.

Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to change originating IP in HttpWebRequest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345387/how-to-change-originating-ip-in-httpwebrequest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[how to change originating IP in HttpWebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345387/how-to-change-originating-ip-in-httpwebrequest)

Check out that post, looks like the exact question and answer you are asking :) cheers!

Comment: Thank you very much! I also found this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515000/choosing-which-ip-the-http-request-is-using-when-having-multiple-ips-net) which also helped. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This is a controlled by the networking configuration in the operating system. Look into using routing metrics so that the desired IP interface shows up with the least cost path to your destination.