# How to set a specific ip address on httpwebrequest c#?

Tags: c#, proxy, ip, port, webrequest

This is my code. I want to make this webrequest from ip address 172.17.2.1. Is it possible?

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://m.facebook.com");
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
request.CookieContainer.Add(cookies);

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
cookies = response.Cookies;
```

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515000/choosing-which-ip-the-http-request-is-using-when-having-multiple-ips-net